# MIPS linked list

Tags: linked-list, mips, singly-linked-list

I'm confused exactly about how to create structures in MIPS. I want to create a linked list implementation which computes the length of the strings stored, and sorts them in stored-order. Here is my code so far:

```
# Global symbols
#
    # string routines
    .globl read_string
    .globl strcmp
    .globl strlen
    .globl trim
    .globl strloop
    .globl replace

    # list routines
    .globl insert
    .globl insert_here
    .globl print_list

    .globl  main

    # pseudo-standard library
    .globl get_string
    .globl malloc
    .globl print_newline
    .globl print_string


##################################################
# Constants
#
        .data
MAX_STR_LEN: .word 50
STR_NEWLINE: .asciiz "\n"
STR_ENTER:   .asciiz "enter a string: "



#################################################################
#################################################################
# Code
#
    .text


##################################################
# main: repeatedly gets strings from user and enters them in list
# until a string of length less than two is entered;
# prints list in order when done
#
main:   
#   lines commented out - not needed in simulation:
#   addi $sp, $sp, -12
#   sw   $ra, 0($sp)
#   sw   $s0, 4($sp) #$s0 will be linked list
#   sw   $s1, 8($sp) #$s1 will be the current string
    li      $s0, 0  # initialize the list to NULL

Loop_main:
    la      $a0, STR_ENTER
    jal     print_string
    jal     read_string
    move    $s1, $v0
    jal     trim
    jal     strlen
    addi    $t0, $zero, 2
    beq     $v0, $t0, Exit_loop_main
    jal     strcmp
    jal     insert
    # replace newline with null terminator
    # ...

    # check string length; exit loop if less than 2
    # ...

    # insert string into list
    # ...
    # reassign front of list
    j       Loop_main

Exit_loop_main:
    move    $a0, $s0
    jal     print_list
    jal     print_newline
#   lines commented out - not needed in simulation:
#   lw   $s1, 8($sp)
#   lw   $s0, 4($sp)
#   lw   $ra, 0($sp)
#   addi $sp, $sp, 12
#   jr   $ra        
    # exit simulation via syscall
    li      $v0, 10
    syscall



##################################################
# String routines
#

# read_string: allocates MAX_STR_LEN bytes for a string
# and then reads a string from standard input into that memory address
# and returns the address in $v0
read_string:
    addi    $sp, $sp, -8            #allocate space for 2 items on the stack
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)             #push the jump register onto the stack
    sw      $s0, 4($sp)             #push the head of the list onto the stack
    add     $t0, $t0, $zero         #$t0 gets 0  
    la      $t1, MAX_STR_LEN        #$a0 gets MAX_STR_LEN
    lw      $a0, 0($t1)             #move MAX_STR_LEN from $t1 into $a0 
    jal     malloc                  #jump to malloc to allocate space for string
    move    $a0, $v0                #move pointer to allocated memory to $a0
    add     $t1, $t1, $zero         #get zero
    move    $a1, $t1                #move zero to a1
    la      $a1, MAX_STR_LEN        #$a1 gets MAX_STR_LEN
    jal     get_string              #get the string into $v0
    lw      $s0, 4($sp)             #load the head of the list
    lw      $ra, 0($sp)             #load the jump address
    addi    $sp, $sp, 8             #push onto the stack space for 2 elements
    jr      $ra                     #jump back to caller function


# trim: modifies string stored at address in $a0 so that
# first occurrence of a newline is replaced by null terminator
trim:
    li      $t0, 10                 #$t1 gets 10, ASCII value for newline
strloop:   
    lb      $t1, 0($a0)             #get byte of character of string and loop 
    beq     $t1, $t0, replace       #if $a0 = go to replace
    addi    $a0, $a0, 8             #increment $a0 by 8 to piont to first bit of next char
    j       strloop                 #jump back to beginning
replace:    
    add     $t2, $t2, $zero         #$t2 is set to zero, ASCII value for null terminator
    sb      $t2, 0($a0)             #$t2 is stored into the byte starting at $a0
    jr      $ra                     #jump back to caller

# strlen: given string stored at address in $a0
# returns its length in $v0
strlen: 
    add     $t0, $t0, $zero         #$t0 gets zero
lenloop:    
    lb      $t1, 0($a0)             #get the first byte for first char in $a0
    beq     $t1, $zero, exitline    #if $t1 == 0 (null terminator), jump to exit
    addi    $a0, $a0, 8             #else, increment to next byte of string for next char
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1             #increment $t0 for each character in string
    j       lenloop                 #jump back up to loop 
exitline:   
    sw      $t0, 0($v0)             #store $t0 into $v0 to return lenght of string
    jr      $ra                     #jump back to caller 



# strcmp: given strings s, t stored at addresses in $a0, $a1
# returns -1 if s < t; 0 if s == t, 1 if s > t
strcmp:
    lb      $t0, 0($a0)             #get byte of first char in string s 
    lb      $t1, 0($a1)             #get byte of first char in string t
  #  lb         $t3, 0($t0)
    #lb         $t4, 0($t1)
    addi    $t3, $t3, 1             #get 1 to compare
    slt     $t2, $t0, $t1           #if s[0] < t[0] $t2 = 1, else $t2 = 0
    bne     $t2, $t3, lessthan      #if $t2  == 1, jump to lessthan
    slt     $t2, $t1, $t0           #if t[0] < s[1], $t2 = 1, else $t2 = 0
    beq     $t2, $t3, greaterthan   #if $t2 == 1, jump to greaterthan
    sw      $zero, 0($v0)           #$v0 gets zero 
    j       end
lessthan: 
    addi    $t4, $t4, -1            #$t4 gets -1
    sw      $t4, 0($v0)             #$v0 gets -1 
    j       end                     #jump to end
greaterthan: 
    addi    $t4, $t4, 1             #$t4 gets 1
    sw      $t4, 0($v0)             #$v0 gets 1
    j       end                     #jump to end
end:      
    jr      $ra

# insert_here: given address of front of list in $a0 
# and address of string to insert in $a1, 
# inserts new linked-list node in front of list;
# returns address of new front of list in $v0
insert_here:
    lw      $t0, 0($a0)             #$t0 get $a0
    lw      $t1, 0($a1)             #$t1 gets $a1
    addi    $t2, $zero, 8           #$t2 gets 8 
    sw      $t2, 0($a0)             #$t2 gets stored into $a0
    jal     malloc                  #allocate 1 byte for the memory
    move    $t3, $v0                #get address of new memory from $v0 and move to $t3
    sw      $t1, 0($t3)             #store the string pointer into bytes 0-3 of the new memory
    sw      $t0, 4($t3)             #store the pointer to the original front of the list 
    sw      $t3, 0($s0)             #store the new node into $s0
    lw      $ra, 0($sp)             #pop the register to jump back to off the stack 
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4             #add to the stack
    jr      $ra                     #jump back to caller



##################################################
# List routines
#


# insert: given address of front of list in $a0 
# and address of string to insert in $a1, 
# inserts new linked-list node in appropriate place in list 
# ...
# returns address of new front of list in $v0 (which may be same as old)
insert: 
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4             #add space on the stack
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)             #store jump register onto the stack 
    lw      $t9, 0($a0)             #load head of the list for later use
    lw      $t0, 0($a0)             #load head of list into $t0
    andi    $t0, $t0, 240           #bitwise and with 240 (1111 0000) to extract first 4 bits for pointer to string
    sw      $t0, 0($a0)             #store $t0 into $a0 for strcmp call
    lb      $t6, 0($t0)             #get the byte of the first string char in the list
    lw      $t7, 0($a1)             #get address of string 
    lb      $t1, 0($t7)             #get the byte of the first char of the string
    addi    $t3, $zero, 1           #$t3 gets 1
    addi    $t4, $zero, -1          #$t3 gets -1
alphloop:                           #be careful in this function may have a bug with front of the list 
#   slt     $t2, $t1, $t0           #if $t1 < $t0, then $t2 = 1, else $t2 = 0 
#   beq     $t2, $t3, put           #if 
#   beq     $t2, $zero, nextchar
    jal     strcmp                  #compare the strings in $a0 and $a1 
    move    $t5, $v0                #move the value returned from strcmp into $t5
    beq     $t5, $t4, put           #if $t5 = -1, then value is less and then put new string at head of list
    beq     $t5, $t3, nextstring    #if $t5 = 1, then the head of the list is larger than the string and go to next string
    beq     $t5, $zero, close       #check if it is zero, if so it is already in the list so step out 
nextstring:
    lw      $t2, 0($a0)             #store pointer to next node in $t2
    andi    $t8, $t9, 15            #get address of next node string
    beq     $t8, $zero, put         #if it points to null then add node at the end
    sw      $t8, 0($a0)             #store into $a0 
    j       alphloop                #check against the next string in loop
put:    
    li      $t5, 8                  #$t5 gets 8 
    move    $a0, $t5                #$t5 moved into $a0 
    jal     malloc                  #allocate size for node 
    move    $t5, $v0                #move address returned by malloc to $t5
    sw      $a1, 0($t5)             #store $a1 into address allocated
    beq     $t2, $zero, front       #node is at front of the list, so there is no need to update pointer
    sw      $t2, 4($t5)             #store pointer to current node into new node
    addi    $t0, $a0, -8            #subtract from the current node back one 
    sw      $t5, 0($t0)             #store new pointer into the node
    jr      $ra
front: 
    sw      $t5, 0($s0)             #make global reference to front of the node the new node if its at the front
close:    
    jr      $ra                     #jump back 


# print_list: given address of front of list in $a0
# prints each string in list, one per line, in order
print_list:
    addi    $sp, $sp, -8
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)
    sw      $s0, 4($sp)
    move    $s0, $a0
    beq     $s0, $zero, Exit_print_list
Loop_print_list:
    lw      $a0, 0($s0)
    jal     print_string
    jal     print_newline
    lw      $s0, 4($s0) # node = node->next
    bne     $s0, $zero, Loop_print_list
Exit_print_list:
    lw      $s0, 4($sp)
    lw      $ra, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 8
    jr      $ra



##################################################
# Pseudo-standard library routines:
#   wrappers around SPIM/MARS syscalls
#

# assumes buffer to read into is in $a0, and max length is in $a1
get_string:
    li      $v0, 8
            syscall
    jr      $ra

# malloc: takes one argument (in $a0) which indicates how many bytes
# to allocate; returns a pointer to the allocated memory (in $v0)
malloc: 
    li      $v0, 9  # SPIM/MARS code for "sbrk" memory allocation
            syscall
    jr      $ra

# print_newline: displays newline to standard output
print_newline:
    li      $v0, 4
    la      $a0, STR_NEWLINE
            syscall
    jr      $ra

# print_string: displays supplied string (in $a0) to standard output
print_string:
    li      $v0, 4
            syscall  
    jr      $ra
```

Where should I go from here? My code assembles but does not do anything after reading in two inputs.

Comment: That's really long. You'd stand a better chance of getting an answer if you cut it down to the minimum possible length

Comment: @KonradLindenbach Yes, it was long, but I've just posted a full answer. IMO, after analyzing it, OP really _did_ need to post that much. And the answer I gave [with annotation, discussion, etc.] was ~24,000 chars [cut down from 29,000]. The annotated source was 50% of it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You did a great job with your level of commenting, style, and the program layout. Some of the best I've seen on SO. Overall, a good effort.

However, there *were* bugs.

I've produced an annotated version of your code and a refactored one. See below.

---

There were a number of bugs throughout the code, *not* related to the struct or insert code [there were at least 26 such bugs].

A frequent one was often repeating a wrong single instruction. This was often wanting to set a register with a constant. Your code used (e.g.) `addi $t3,$t3,7` instead of the correct `addi $t3,$zero,7`. I replaced those with `li $t3,7`. In a few places, you *did* use the correct version, so I'd call this a "typo" bug, but there were a *lot* of them.

Your `strcmp` only compared the first character and not the whole string.

The actual insertion code was a bit convoluted and much more complicated than it needed to be (e.g. `insert_here` wasn't used). It also had some severe logic/implementation bugs. You were on the right track, but, after fixing so many other unrelated bugs, I decided to rewrite it rather than try to patch it.

---

Here's the annotated version [stripped down for SO space limits] where I fixed most of the one line bugs [annotated with "BUG"], but the code is still *not* yet runnable and *no* fixes to the struct/insert logic. I tried to remain faithful to your original code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
main:
    # BUGBAD: this is the list pointer but it is _never_ set to a non-null
    # value but things get stored relative to it
    li      $s0,0                   # initialize the list to NULL

Loop_main:
    la      $a0,STR_ENTER
    jal     print_string
    jal     read_string
    move    $s1,$v0

    # BUG: trim uses and trashes a0 but strlen needs the original value
    jal     trim
    jal     strlen
    addi    $t0,$zero,2
    beq     $v0,$t0,Exit_loop_main

    # BUG: this strcmp serves _no_ purpose
    jal     strcmp

    jal     insert
    # replace newline with null terminator
    # ...

    # check string length; exit loop if less than 2
    # ...

    # insert string into list
    # ...
    # reassign front of list
    j       Loop_main

Exit_loop_main:
    move    $a0,$s0
    jal     print_list
    jal     print_newline

    li      $v0,10
    syscall

read_string:
    addi    $sp,$sp,-8
    sw      $ra,0($sp)
    sw      $s0,4($sp)

    # BUG: this does _not_ set t0 = 0
    ###add      $t0,$t0,$zero       # $t0 gets 0
    li      $t0,0
    # BUGFIX

    # BUG: MAX_STR_LEN should be a _constant_ (e.g. 80) but this is an _address_
    ###la       $t1,MAX_STR_LEN         # $a0 gets MAX_STR_LEN
    lw      $t1,MAX_STR_LEN         # $a0 gets MAX_STR_LEN
    # BUGFIX

    lw      $a0,0($t1)              # move MAX_STR_LEN from $t1 into $a0
    jal     malloc                  # allocate space for string
    move    $a0,$v0                 # move pointer to allocated memory to $a0

    # BUG: this does _not_ set t1 = 0
    ###add      $t1,$t1,$zero           # get zero
    li      $t1,0                   # get zero
    # BUGFIX

    move    $a1,$t1                 # move zero to a1

    # BUG: this does not set a1 = 50
    ###la       $a1,MAX_STR_LEN         # $a1 gets MAX_STR_LEN
    lw      $a1,MAX_STR_LEN         # $a1 gets MAX_STR_LEN
    # BUGFIX
    jal     get_string              # get the string into $v0

    lw      $s0,4($sp)
    lw      $ra,0($sp)
    addi    $sp,$sp,8
    jr      $ra

# trim: modifies string stored at address in $a0 so that
# first occurrence of a newline is replaced by null terminator
trim:
    # NOTE: using hex for this would be better (e.g. 0x0A)
    li      $t0,10                  # $t1 gets 10, ASCII value for newline

strloop:
    lb      $t1,0($a0)              # get byte of char of string and loop
    beq     $t1,$t0,replace         # if $a0 = go to replace
    # BUG: the increment should be 1
    ###addi $a0,$a0,8               # increment $a0 by 8 to piont to first bit of next char
    addi    $a0,$a0,1               # increment $a0 by 1 to point to next char
    # BUGFIX
    j       strloop                 # jump back to beginning

replace:
    # BUG: this does _not_ set t2 to 0
    ###add      $t2,$t2,$zero           # $t2 is set to zero, ASCII value for null terminator
    li      $t2,0                   # t2 = zero, ASCII value for EOS
    # BUGFIX

    sb      $t2,0($a0)              # $t2 is stored into byte at $a0
    jr      $ra                     # jump back to caller

# strlen: given string stored at address in $a0
# returns its length in $v0
strlen:
    # BUG: this does _not_ set t0 to zero
    ###add      $t0,$t0,$zero           # $t0 gets zero
    li      $t0,0
    # BUGFIX

lenloop:
    lb      $t1,0($a0)              # get the first byte for first char in $a0
    beq     $t1,$zero,exitline      # if $t1 == 0 (null terminator), exit

    # BUG: the increment here is wrong -- it should be 1
    ###addi $a0,$a0,8               # else, increment to next byte of string for next char
    addi    $a0,$a0,4               # else, increment to next byte of string
    # BUGFIX

    addi    $t0,$t0,1               # increment $t0 for each char in string
    j       lenloop                 # jump back up to loop

exitline:
    # BUG: this stores the length at the _address_ pointed to in v0
    ###sw       $t0,0($v0)              # store $t0 into $v0 to return lenght of string
    move    $v0,$t0
    # BUGFIX
    jr      $ra                     # jump back to caller

# BUG: this only compares the first character
# strcmp: given strings s, t stored at addresses in $a0, $a1
# returns -1 if s < t; 0 if s == t, 1 if s > t
strcmp:
    lb      $t0,0($a0)              # get byte of first char in string s
    lb      $t1,0($a1)              # get byte of first char in string t
    #  lb         $t3, 0($t0)
    # lb         $t4, 0($t1)
    # BUG: this does not set t3 = 1
    ###addi $t3,$t3,1               # get 1 to compare
    li      $t3,1
    # BUGFIX
    slt     $t2,$t0,$t1             # if s[0] < t[0] $t2 = 1, else $t2 = 0
    bne     $t2,$t3,lessthan        # if $t2  == 1, jump to lessthan
    slt     $t2,$t1,$t0             # if t[0] < s[1], $t2 = 1, else $t2 = 0
    beq     $t2,$t3,greaterthan     # if $t2 == 1, jump to greaterthan
    # BUG: this does not set v0 = 0
    ###sw       $zero,0($v0)            # $v0 gets zero
    li      $v0,0
    # BUGFIX
    j       end

lessthan:
    # BUG: this does _not_ set t4 = -1
    ###addi $t4,$t4,-1              # $t4 gets -1
    li      $t4,-1
    # BUGFIX
    # BUG: this does not set v0
    ###sw       $t4,0($v0)              # $v0 gets -1
    move    $v0,$t4
    # BUGFIX
    j       end                     # jump to end

greaterthan:
    # BUG: this does _not_ set t4 = 1
    ###addi $t4,$t4,1               # $t4 gets 1
    li      $t4,1
    # BUGFIX
    # BUG: this does not set v0
    ###sw       $t4,0($v0)              # $v0 gets 1
    move    $v0,$t4
    # BUGFIX
    j       end                     # jump to end

end:
    jr      $ra

# BUG: the front of the list is _always_ s0
# insert: given address of front of list in $a0
# and address of string to insert in $a1,
# inserts new linked-list node in appropriate place in list
# ...
# returns address of new front of list in $v0 (which may be same as old)
insert:
    # BUG: should be -4
    ###addi $sp,$sp,4
    addi    $sp,$sp,-4
    # BUGFIX
    sw      $ra,0($sp)

    lw      $t9,0($a0)              # load head of the list for later use
    lw      $t0,0($a0)              # load head of list into $t0

    # BUG: anding a _pointer_ against 0xF0 makes _no_ sense
    # NOTE: better to use hex for bit patterns
    ###andi $t0,$t0,240             # bitwise and with 240 (1111 0000) to extract first 4 bits for pointer to string
    # BUGFIX

    # BUG: this block of code is on the right track, but, wrong
    # storing into a0 (the struct) for strcmp makes _no_ sense
    sw      $t0,0($a0)              # store $t0 into $a0 for strcmp call
    lb      $t6,0($t0)              # get the byte of the first string char in the list
    lw      $t7,0($a1)              # get address of string
    lb      $t1,0($t7)              # get the byte of the first char of the string

    # NOTE: while we can set these here, we're burning two regs across the
    # strcmp call -- cleaner to move this below the call
    addi    $t3,$zero,1             # $t3 gets 1
    addi    $t4,$zero,-1            # $t3 gets -1

# be careful in this function may have a bug with front of the list
alphloop:
    #   slt     $t2, $t1, $t0           #if $t1 < $t0, then $t2 = 1, else $t2 = 0
    #   beq     $t2, $t3, put           #if
    #   beq     $t2, $zero, nextchar

    # BUG: strcmp destroys the values of a0 and a1, so the second time through
    # here they have bogus values
    # BUGBAD: strcmp uses them as pointers to the _strings_ but here, we're using
    # a0 as a _struct_ pointer!!!
    jal     strcmp                  # compare the strings in $a0 and $a1
    move    $t5,$v0                 # move the value returned from strcmp into $t5
    beq     $t5,$t4,put             # if $t5 == -1, then value is less and then put new string at head of list
    beq     $t5,$t3,nextstring      # if $t5 == 1, then the head of the list is larger than the string and go to next string
    beq     $t5,$zero,close         # check if it is zero, if so it is already in the list so step out

nextstring:
    lw      $t2,0($a0)              # store pointer to next node in $t2

    # NOTE: use hex for bit masks (e.g. 0x0F)
    # BUG: this makes no sense
    andi    $t8,$t9,15              # get address of next node string

    beq     $t8,$zero,put           # if it points to null then add node at the end
    sw      $t8,0($a0)              # store into $a0
    j       alphloop                # check against the next string in loop

put:
    # NOTE: what is 8??? obviously, it's the size in bytes of a node, so the
    # comment should say that
    li      $t5,8                   # $t5 gets 8
    move    $a0,$t5                 # $t5 moved into $a0
    jal     malloc                  # allocate size for node
    move    $t5,$v0                 # move address returned by malloc to $t5

    sw      $a1,0($t5)              # store $a1 into address allocated
    beq     $t2,$zero,front         # node is at front of the list, so there is no need to update pointer
    sw      $t2,4($t5)              # store pointer to current node into new node
    addi    $t0,$a0,-8              # subtract from the current node back one
    sw      $t5,0($t0)              # store new pointer into the node
    jr      $ra

front:
    sw      $t5,0($s0)              # make global reference to front of the node the new node if its at the front

close:
    jr      $ra
```

---

Here's the cleaned up, refactored, corrected, and runnable code.

A few things I recommend:

(1) For labels within a function, to avoid conflicts with other functions, the labels should be prefixed with the function name (e.g. for your `trim` function [which I renamed to `nltrim`], you had a label `strloop` [which I renamed to `nltrim_loop`])

(2) Comments should describe intent in real world terms and not just describe the actual asm instruction.

I realize you're just starting out, but (e.g.) this:

```
addi $t3,$zero,7  # sets the value of $t3 to 7
```

Should be replaced with something more descriptive:

```
addi $t3,$zero,7  # count = 7
```

(3) The general rule is to put a sidebar comment on *every* line [which you did]. It's what I do, mostly. But, for some boilerplate, that is well understood, the comments may be overkill [and may actually interfere with readability].

For example, the code that establishes a stack frame for a function and the code that restores from that frame at function exit is well understood. So, maybe a single block comment at the top like `# set up stack frame` for the few lines and `# restore from stack frame` at the bottom rather comments on each inst

(4) Keep sidebar comments short so that they fit in 80 columns. If you need more, elevate the comment to a full line block comment above the instruction [and use as many lines as you wish]

(5) For difficult/complex stuff, it's okay to prototype using pseudo-code, or actual C [or a language of your choice]. It's a reasonable assumption that anyone writing [or reading] asm code is familiar with at least one high level language [C being the most likely].

For the struct code, I added a C struct definition in a top block comment. In the `insert` routine, I added the C pseudo-code in the top comment block. The sidebar comments for the asm often referred to the symbols and actions in the pseudo code

Actually, doing this prototyping even for simpler functions has benefits [even if you don't add the code as comments]. (e.g.) It may have helped when writing your `strcmp`

(6) Keep the code as simple as possible. When the code is needlessly complicated, it makes it very easy to introduce bugs in your program logic or use incorrect instructions to implement that logic. It also makes it difficult to spot these bugs later.

(e.g.) In certain cases, your code was loading a register, only to have to move it later. Thus, using 2-3 insts where only one was necessary. Try to minimize unnecessary register movement [not just for speed, but simpler code].

For example, your `strcmp` had 24 lines, and only compared the first char [i.e. a bug], and had several branches. My version was only 12 lines, did the full string compare, and was a simple loop.

Likewise, in your insertion code, `insert_here` [not used] was 17 lines and `insert` was 47 lines for a total of 64. My working version was 31 lines.

*Note:* I used the `.eqv` pseudo-op to "define" struct offsets. I use `mars` and this works for it but I don't know if `spim` supports `.eqv`. You can always hard code the offsets, but it makes the code less readable and prone to error. With structs that have [say] 10 elements, some form of this is quite handy. Most other assemblers have some form of `.eqv` equivalent.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
# Global symbols

# struct node {
#   struct node *node_next;
#   char *node_str;
# };
    .eqv    node_next       0
    .eqv    node_str        4
    .eqv    node_size       8       # sizeof(struct node)

# NOTE: we don't actually use this struct
# struct list {
#   struct node *list_head;
#   struct node *list_tail;
# };
    .eqv    list_head       0
    .eqv    list_tail       4

# string routines
    .globl  read_string
    .globl  strcmp
    .globl  strlen
    .globl  nltrim

# list routines
    .globl  insert
    .globl  print_list

    .globl  main

# pseudo-standard library
    .globl  get_string
    .globl  malloc
    .globl  print_newline
    .globl  print_string

# Constants
    .data
MAX_STR_LEN:    .word   50
STR_NEWLINE:    .asciiz "\n"
STR_ENTER:  .asciiz     "enter a string: "

    # global registers:
    #   s0 -- list head pointer (list_head)

# Code
    .text

# main: repeatedly gets strings from user and enters them in list
# until a string of length less than two is entered;
# prints list in order when done
#
main:

    li      $s0,0                   # list_head = NULL

main_loop:
    # prompt user for string
    la      $a0,STR_ENTER
    jal     print_string

    # read in string from user
    jal     read_string

    # save the string pointer as we'll use it repeatedly
    move    $s1,$v0

    # strip newline
    move    $a0,$s1
    jal     nltrim

    # get string length and save the length
    move    $a0,$s1
    jal     strlen

    # stop if given empty string
    blez    $v0,main_exit

    # insert the string
    jal     insert

    j       main_loop

main_exit:
    move    $a0,$s0
    jal     print_list

    jal     print_newline

    # exit simulation via syscall
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

    ##################################################
    # String routines
    #

# read_string: allocates MAX_STR_LEN bytes for a string
# and then reads a string from standard input into that memory address
# and returns the address in $v0
read_string:
    addi    $sp,$sp,-8
    sw      $ra,0($sp)
    sw      $s0,4($sp)

    lw      $a1,MAX_STR_LEN         # $a1 gets MAX_STR_LEN

    move    $a0,$a1                 # tell malloc the size
    jal     malloc                  # allocate space for string

    move    $a0,$v0                 # move pointer to allocated memory to $a0

    lw      $a1,MAX_STR_LEN         # $a1 gets MAX_STR_LEN
    jal     get_string              # get the string into $v0

    move    $v0,$a0                 # restore string address

    lw      $s0,4($sp)
    lw      $ra,0($sp)
    addi    $sp,$sp,8
    jr      $ra

# nltrim: modifies string stored at address in $a0 so that
# first occurrence of a newline is replaced by null terminator
nltrim:
    li      $t0,0x0A                # ASCII value for newline

nltrim_loop:
    lb      $t1,0($a0)              # get next char in string
    beq     $t1,$t0,nltrim_replace  # is it newline? if yes, fly
    beqz    $t1,nltrim_done         # is it EOS? if yes, fly
    addi    $a0,$a0,1               # increment by 1 to point to next char
    j       nltrim_loop             # loop

nltrim_replace:
    sb      $zero,0($a0)            # zero out the newline

nltrim_done:
    jr      $ra                     # return

# strlen: given string stored at address in $a0
# returns its length in $v0
#
# clobbers:
#   t1 -- current char
strlen:
    move    $v0,$a0                 # remember base address

strlen_loop:
    lb      $t1,0($a0)              # get the current char
    addi    $a0,$a0,1               # pre-increment to next byte of string
    bnez    $t1,strlen_loop         # is char 0? if no, loop

    subu    $v0,$a0,$v0             # get length + 1
    subi    $v0,$v0,1               # get length (compensate for pre-increment)
    jr      $ra                     # return

# strcmp: given strings s, t stored at addresses in $a0, $a1
# returns <0 if s < t; 0 if s == t, >0 if s > t
# clobbers: t0, t1
strcmp:
    lb      $t0,0($a0)              # get byte of first char in string s
    lb      $t1,0($a1)              # get byte of first char in string t

    sub     $v0,$t0,$t1             # compare them
    bnez    $v0,strcmp_done         # mismatch? if yes, fly

    addi    $a0,$a0,1               # advance s pointer
    addi    $a1,$a1,1               # advance t pointer

    bnez    $t0,strcmp              # at EOS? no=loop, otherwise v0 == 0

strcmp_done:
    jr      $ra                     # return

# insert: inserts new linked-list node in appropriate place in list
#
# returns address of new front of list in $s0 (which may be same as old)
#
# arguments:
#   s0 -- pointer to node at front of list (can be NULL)
#   s1 -- address of string to insert (strptr)
#
# registers:
#   s2 -- address of new node to be inserted (new)
#   s3 -- address of previous node in list (prev)
#   s4 -- address of current node in list (cur)
#
# clobbers:
#   a0, a1 (from strcmp)
#
# pseudo-code:
#     // allocate new node
#     new = malloc(node_size);
#     new->node_next = NULL;
#     new->node_str = strptr;
#
#     // for loop:
#     prev = NULL;
#     for (cur = list_head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->node_next) {
#         if (strcmp(new->node_str,cur->node_str) < 0)
#             break;
#         prev = cur;
#     }
#
#     // insertion:
#     new->node_next = cur;
#     if (prev != NULL)
#         prev->node_next = new;
#     else
#         list_head = new;
insert:
    addi    $sp,$sp,-4
    sw      $ra,0($sp)

    # allocate a new node -- do this first as we'll _always_ need it
    li      $a0,node_size           # get the struct size
    jal     malloc
    move    $s2,$v0                 # remember the address

    # initialize the new node
    sw      $zero,node_next($s2)    # new->node_next = NULL
    sw      $s1,node_str($s2)       # new->node_str = strptr

    # set up for loop
    li      $s3,0                   # prev = NULL
    move    $s4,$s0                 # cur = list_head
    j       insert_test

insert_loop:
    lw      $a0,node_str($s2)       # get new string address
    lw      $a1,node_str($s4)       # get current string address
    jal     strcmp                  # compare them -- new < cur?
    bltz    $v0,insert_now          # if yes, insert after prev

    move    $s3,$s4                 # prev = cur

    lw      $s4,node_next($s4)      # cur = cur->node_next

insert_test:
    bnez    $s4,insert_loop         # cur == NULL? if no, loop

insert_now:
    sw      $s4,node_next($s2)      # new->node_next = cur
    beqz    $s3,insert_front        # prev == NULL? if yes, fly
    sw      $s2,node_next($s3)      # prev->node_next = new
    j       insert_done

insert_front:
    move    $s0,$s2                 # list_head = new

insert_done:
    lw      $ra,0($sp)
    addi    $sp,$sp,4
    jr      $ra

# print_list: given address of front of list in $a0
# prints each string in list, one per line, in order
print_list:
    addi    $sp,$sp,-8
    sw      $ra,0($sp)
    sw      $s0,4($sp)

    beq     $s0,$zero,print_list_exit

print_list_loop:
    lw      $a0,node_str($s0)
    jal     print_string
    jal     print_newline
    lw      $s0,node_next($s0)      # node = node->node_next
    bnez    $s0,print_list_loop

print_list_exit:
    lw      $s0,4($sp)
    lw      $ra,0($sp)
    addi    $sp,$sp,8
    jr      $ra

    # Pseudo-standard library routines:
    #   wrappers around SPIM/MARS syscalls
    #

# assumes buffer to read into is in $a0, and max length is in $a1
get_string:
    li      $v0,8
    syscall
    jr      $ra

# malloc: takes one argument (in $a0) which indicates how many bytes
# to allocate; returns a pointer to the allocated memory (in $v0)
malloc:
    li      $v0,9                   # SPIM/MARS code for "sbrk"
    syscall
    jr      $ra

# print_newline: displays newline to standard output
print_newline:
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,STR_NEWLINE
    syscall
    jr      $ra

# print_string: displays supplied string (in $a0) to standard output
print_string:
    li      $v0,4
    syscall
    jr      $ra
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I agree with the line-by-line comments, as it helps me understand exactly what registers I intended to access(or messup in the previous case).

The rationale is simple. Imagine the converse: a large [5000 line] asm file with *no* comments that is known to have a bug. You can't trust the logic/algorithm [it may have the bug]. You can't trust the implementation [it may have the bug]. Whenever I get a case like that, I add the comments as I've described *before* even looking for the bug (i.e. I'm learning the algorithm and the code as I do this).

This is doing a code review. I'll do it even if the file already has comments [as yours did]. I often do this review for code I've just written that I think is "complete" [i.e. all code that needs to be written, has been].

If I finish late in the day, I'll do the review as the first thing next day. Often, "sleeping on it" makes it easy to spot bugs that I *wouldn't* have found in a review on the prior day [because I was still "too close" to the problem]. If what I'm writing is going to take multiple days, I always review the prior day's work as the first thing.

Even with your original comments that were like (2), it helped me find your "typo" bugs. When I saw `add $t1,$t1,$zero #get zero` the comment mismatch made it easy to find/fix. It would have 10x harder stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comments *always* help. When originally coding `insert`, I had:

```
    jal     strcmp                  # compare them -- new < cur?
    bgtz    $v0,insert_now          # if yes, insert after prev
```

I got high-to-low output.

At first, I suspected `strcmp` as it was [equally] new code. I usually review the lower level function before I review the call(s) to it. I did a code review of `strcmp` and it seemed fine. But, I still wasn't convinced. I wrote some diagnostic code [unit tests] for `strcmp`, but it passed.

Then, I noticed the comments vs the code in `insert` above. The fix was easy: Change `bgtz` to `bltz`.

Another good rule is: Don't break [introduce a bug into] *existing* [working] code.

When I first reviewed `print_list`, I thought: "it's using [and trashing] s0". This was okay because after calling it, the program was terminating. But, not if it were called multiple times. I had *missed* the fact that you *were* saving/restoring s0 on the stack [which I realized on the *second* reading].

> Its refreshing to see an experienced be so encouraging to a newbie like me

We've all been newbies at some point. No harm, no foul.

Even veteran programmers create bugs [sometimes, multiple ones / day]. Bugs are *not* an indictment of one's soul/character. Bugs are just a *normal* by-product of being a programmer [just as finding/fixing them is].

IMO, the keys are:

(1) Willingness to learn

(2) Admit mistakes (e.g.) President Kennedy [after the "Bay of Pigs"]: *"Mistakes are not errors, if we admit them"*

(3) Most importantly, leave **ego** out of it.

The *weakest* programmers, when a bug [or suspected bug] is reported are the ones that:

(1) Say that their code is working [without even checking to see if the bug report has merit].

(2) Deny the bug as not really a bug [when it is]

(3) Refuse to generate [or accept] test cases that can/do prove/disprove a bug

(4) Be [deliberately] "slow" to produce the bug fix [it's not as much fun as new code]

(5) During slack time, refuse to "clean up" code that *is* working, but is *also* poorly structured [and *should* be refactored]

(6) Treat customers with disdain [i.e. "they're all idiots"]

IMO, *good* programmers, on the other hand, are *proactive* when it comes to bugs [or *potential* bugs].

At one company I was at, we had a shipping product [a realtime video processing platform] that had no *apparent* bugs. We were in slack time. But, my boss [who was also a good programmer] and I had a suspicion about some code. No bug report, no hard evidence, just a hunch. So, we did a review.

Sure enough, there *was* a bug. But, it would only trigger for an *obscure* edge case. We believed that it was too obscure for a customer to ever see it, as *we* had *never* actually seen it ourselves in our lab despite *all* our test video clips. We *only* found it by the code review. But, *"bugs are bugs"*, so I started the fix.

About two weeks later, the customer support rep for our *major* client comes in with a report of some intermittent distortion in the video they were seeing [about once every 2-3 days].

Could this distortion come from the bug I was working on? I didn't have my full fix yet, but, by that time, I *did* have a unit test that could generate the bug. In the lab, I triggered it for the rep. He said: "Yes, that's it--the distortion the client is seeing"

The bug had been introduced about 3 months earlier. The client just had different video than we had, that made the bug occurrence much more likely.

By being proactive, we were able to [honestly] tell the client that we were "already on top of it" and we shortened the turnaround time for the fix to the client by two weeks. Both of which, endeared us to them [i.e. they bought more gear from us].

Comment: I really disagree with you about putting a comment on every line. That's gratuitous noise. I really believe that assembly should be commented and indented like every other language.

Comment: @KonradLindenbach You're disagreeing with (3). But, did you catch the second sentence about leaving them off sometimes? I wrote my first asm pgm 40+ years ago. I've also seen plenty I didn't write. Most of the time, asm _is_ sidebar commented. IBM did entire mainframe OSes in asm. And, they commented every line [I've even worked on one]. A good cmt [in any lang] shows _intent_ (the "what/why"). The asm is the "how". For asm, a cmt like "set $t1 to value of six" _is_ useless, but "x = 6" ["x" should be documented in the top cmt block for the fnc] _is_ useful.

Comment: @KonradLindenbach It allows a "cross-check" between the algorithm and the code. (e.g.) Above, maybe `x = 6` is what you intend, but, you picked the wrong reg (i.e. it should have been $t2). Trying to "divine" the intent from the asm (i.e.) implementation can be problematic. In a higher level lang, code needs a balance between code and cmts (i.e. it's easier to see intent from the code). But, you can't give a more descriptive name to a register [without using `.eqv cur $s4`--which I don't recommend as reg usage is too local/transient], so cmts that show control/algorithm flow help

Comment: @CraigEstey wow, not only does this answer my question -- it also taught me more about how to approach programming in asm. I agree with the line-by-line comments, as it helps me understand exactly what registers I intended to access(or messup in the previous case). Also a side note, I really appreciate the helpfulness and thorough nature of your reply. Its refreshing to see an experienced be so encouraging to a newbie like me :)