# Mars Mips , how to represent struct and list

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I need to represent in MIPS assembly a simple struct like :

```
 struct  User {
       int  id;       
       char name[8];
       int  age;
       int  average_vote;       
   }User;
```

I also need to put  and delete (by id) this user in a queue

Comment: Allocate enough storage, then access the fields with an offset.

Comment: To see an example of how to define/use a struct in MIPS, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538325/mips-linked-list/36560575#36560575