# Converting C array operations to Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I am struggling trying to convert `a[i+1] = a[i-1] + b[4]` to assembly. Where `$s0` is the address of `a`, `$s1` is the address of `b`, and `$s2` is the variable `i`. Professor mentions it can be done in 6 steps.

I have:

```
addi $t0, $s2, 4 #i + 1

addi $t1, $s2, -4 #i - 1

lw $t2, $t1($s0) #load a[i-1] - I know this is wrong

lw $t3, 16($s1) #load b[4]

add $t4, $t2, $t3 #add a[i-1] + b[4]

sw $t4, $t0($s0) #save to a[i+1] - I know this is wrong
```

The areas I know where it is wrong, I know I can't use a register for the immediate, but I am unsure how to tackle this problem otherwise. I might also be doing this completely wrong, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: what if you add I to a (addi %t0, $s0, $s2) then use a +/-4 immediate offset to that?

Comment: Did you try adding `i` to `a`, loading from `a - 1`, adding from `b + 4`, and storing to `a + 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some annotated code that I believe will work:

```
    .text

    .globl  main
# main -- main program
#
# a[i + 1] = a[i - 1] + b[4]
#
# arguments:
#   s0 -- address of a
#   s1 -- address of b
#   s2 -- i
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- address of a[i]
#   t1 -- value of b[4]
#   t2 -- i << 2 (i.e. a byte offset)
#   t3 -- value of a[i - 1]
#   t4 -- a[i - 1] + b[4]
main:
    sll     $t2,$s2,2               # get i << 2
    add     $t0,$s0,$t2             # get &a[i]

    lw      $t3,-4($t0)             # get a[i - 1]
    lw      $t1,16($s1)             # get b[4]

    add     $t4,$t3,$t1             # sum them
    sw      $t4,4($t0)              # a[i + 1] = sum
```

This is pretty close to the *only* sequence that can be used. The order of the `lw` instructions can be flipped but, otherwise, the instructions *must* be those shown, except for using different registers to hold different values.

For *clarity*, each intermediate term/step got its own `t` register. But, we can reduce the number of registers used if reassign/reuse registers. For example, in the first two instructions, we could replace `$t2` with `$t0`, as we never use `$t2` after that.

An optimizing compiler could/would do this. We'd end up needing only `$t0-$t2` instead of `$t0-$t4`:

```
    .text

    .globl  main
# main -- main program
#
# a[i + 1] = a[i - 1] + b[4]
#
# arguments:
#   s0 -- address of a
#   s1 -- address of b
#   s2 -- i
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- i << 2
#         address of a[i]
#   t1 -- value of b[4]
#   t2 -- value of a[i - 1]
#         sum of a[i - 1] + b[4]
main:
    sll     $t0,$s2,2               # get i << 2
    add     $t0,$s0,$t0             # get &a[i]

    lw      $t2,-4($t0)             # get a[i - 1]
    lw      $t1,16($s1)             # get b[4]

    add     $t2,$t2,$t1             # sum them
    sw      $t2,4($t0)              # a[i + 1] = sum
```

If the code is part of a function, we could use `$v0, $v1, $a0` as our temp registers as a function is permitted to use `$v0-$v1` and `$a0-$a3` as internal temporaries if it wishes.

---

**UPDATE:**

> The comments definitely help me understand what is occurring during each instruction

Good programming style [and therefore understanding] has lots of comments. Of the right type. This is *particularly* important for asm because in C, a variable like `number_of_users` is somewhat descriptive. But, `$t0` isn't.

The comments I added are what I would do for any asm code I would write for myself. And, I've been writing asm for decades.

Also, the "optimized" version has a purpose: Simplification. By freeing up `$t3-$t4`, they can be used to hold other things. In a more complex function, this can make the difference between a simple and easily understood one, and a needlessly complicated one that is harder understand and maintain.

For more on this, and tips on how to write asm well, based on my own experience, see my answer: [MIPS linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538325/mips-linked-list/36560575#36560575)

> the professor is not the greatest at relaying information

There is only so much that can be conveyed in a classroom setting. It can cover the basics. And, the coursework can help you learn the basics of the given language. And, IMO, professors have never been particularly good at commenting code well [enough ;-)].

When I was learning asm [on a different architecture], in addition to coursework, I was also able to work as paid programmer on a multiuser timesharing OS that was written 100% in asm. It had the same style of commenting as above.

IMO, one of the best ways to learn is analyze "expert" code. Ask the question: "Why did they do that in *that* way?". That's what I did and I learned a lot. I [still] give credit to that experience to this day.

Comment: Thanks for the response and answer. The comments definitely help me understand what is occurring during each instruction - the professor is not the greatest at relaying information.

Answer (score 1):

```
temp0 = $s0 + $s2
temp2 = load -4(temp0)
temp3 = load 16($s1)
temp1 = temp2 + temp3
store +4(temp0) = temp1
```

Comment: If I am reading the first part correctly, is it saying # $t0 = a[i], correct?

Comment: yes get the address of a[i] then you can offset plus and minus 4 from that right to account for the a[i-1] and a[i+1]   both of those have a[i] as a common variable offset (based on i) then a fixed offset from there.