# Greater then ^ less then in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm doing my homework and trying to implement ROT47 cipher, i wrote pseudocode and stopped at one thing.
Given the following line of pseudocode:

```
if (32 < code < 80) char = ascii_char(code + 47)
if (79 < code < 127) char = ascii_char(code - 47)
```

How could it be translated in MIPS? 
I can imagine how it could be with blt and bgt, but the question here is it possible to make this only with one pseudoinstruction?

Comment: You can do with one branch if you rewrite as `code - 33 < 47` and use unsigned comparison.

Comment: Also obviously you don't need to use pseudoinstructions at all so it can be done with 0 or 1 too :)

Comment: I don’t know if this helps, but equivalent pseudocode is: char = ascii_char(33 + ((code + 14) mod 94))

Comment: Semi-related: [Testing if a value is within one of two ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66893955)