# How can I implement if(x >= '0' && x <= '9') range checks like isdigit in MIPS?

Tags: if-statement, assembly, conditional-statements, mips

I have written the following function to check whether a character is a digit or not:

```
# IsDigit - tests a if a character a digit or not 
# arguments:
#   $a0 = character byte
# return value:
#   $v0 =   1 - digit
#           0 - not a digit
IsDigit:
    lb $t0, ($a0) # obtain the character
    li $t1, 48 # '0' - character
    li $t2, 57 # '9' - character
    bge $t0, $t1, condition1
condition1:
    ble $t0, $t2, condition2

    li $v0, 0
    j return

condition2:
    li $v0, 1

return:                                                                                 
    # return 
    jr $ra
```

Is there any better way to do or write this?

**Edit:** The following is the version-2

```
IsDigit:
    lb $t0, ($a0) # obtain the character
    li $t1, 48 # '0' - character
    li $t2, 57 # '9' - character
    bge $t0, $t1, condition1

    j zero

condition1: 

    ble $t0, $t2, condition2

zero:
    li $v0, 0
    j return

condition2:
    li $v0, 1
    j return

return:                                                                                 
    # return 
    jr $ra
```

**Edit-2**: the following is version-3

```
IsDigit:
    lb $t0, ($a0) # obtain the character
    li $t1, 48 # '0' - character
    li $t2, 57 # '9' - character


    bge $t0, $t1, con1_fulfilled #bigger tha or equal to 0  
    j con1_not_fulfilled

con1_fulfilled:
    ble $t0, $t2, con2_fullfilled #less than or equal to 9
    j con2_not_fulfilled

con2_fullfilled:
    li $v0, 1
    j return

con1_not_fulfilled:
con2_not_fulfilled:
    li $v0, 0

return:                                                                     
    # return 
    jr $ra
```

Comment: Definitely, since it's pointless to branch to the next instruction that would be executed anyway. So `bge $t0, $t1, condition1` makes no sense. That should return 0 but it doesn't.

Comment: @Jester, why return zero?

Comment: Oh okay that's not checking if it's below `'0'` my bad. It's still pointless to go to the next instruction. It doesn't do anything. If it's true it goes to `condition1`, if it's false ... still goes there.

Comment: @Jester, see the version-2 edit.

Comment: That looks better. Of course you can reverse the `bge` to `blt` and then you don't need the `j zero`. Also you don't need the `j return` in `condition2` because that just follows it. The `j return` in `zero` can simply be replaced with `jr $ra` directly too and the `return` label deleted. Also note that `isdigit` doesn't typically take a pointer and your comment doesn't say anything about a pointer either so `lb $t0, ($a0)` is very suspicious. Most likely you already have the character in `$a0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, you use 2 branches that go to past the `if()` body.  If either one is taken, the `if` body doesn't run.  In assembly, you usually want to use the negation of the C condition, because you're jumping past the loop body so it doesn't run.  Your later version does it backwards so also need unconditional `j` instructions, making your code extra complicated.

The opposite of `<=` (le) is `>` (gt).  For C written to use inclusive ranges (le and ge), asm using the same numerical values should branch on the opposite conditions using exclusive ranges (that exclude the `eq`ual case).  Or you can adjust your constants and `bge $t0, '9'+1` or whatever, which can be useful right at the end of what fits into a 16-bit immediate.

```
# this does assemble with MARS or clang, handling pseudo-instructions
# and I think it's correct.
IsDigit:
    lb  $t0, ($a0)    # obtain the character

    blt   $t0, '0', too_low    # if(   $t0 >= '0'  
    bgt   $t0, '9', too_high   #    && $t0 <= '9')
      # fall through into the if body
    li    $v0, 1
    jr    $ra                    # return 1

too_low:
too_high:                    # } else {
    li    $v0, 0

#end_of_else:
    jr    $ra                # return 0
```

If this wasn't at the end of a function, you could `j end_of_else` from the end of the `if` body to jump over the `else` block.  Or in this case, we could have put the `li $v0, 0` ahead of the first `blt`, to fill the load delay slot instead of stalling the pipeline.  (Of course a real MIPS also has branch-delay slots, and you can't have back-to-back branches.  But `bgt` is a pseudo-instruction anyway so there aren't wouldn't really be back-to-back branches.)

Also, instead of jumping to a common `jr $ra`, I simply duplicated the `jr $ra` into the other return path.  If you had more cleanup to do, you might jump to one common return path.  Otherwise tail duplication is a good thing to simplify the branching.

---

In this specific case, **your conditions are related: you're doing a range-check so you only need 1 `sub` and then 1 unsigned-compare against the length of the range.**  See [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536362/what-is-the-idea-behind-32-that-converts-lowercase-letters-to-upper-and-vice/54585515#54585515) for more about range-checks on ASCII characters.

And **since you're returning a boolean 0/1, you don't want to branch at all**, but rather use `sltu` to turn a condition into a 0 or 1 in a registers.  (This is what MIPS uses instead of a FLAGS register like x86 or ARM).  Instructions like `ble` between two registers are pseudo-instructions for `slt` + `bne` anyway; MIPS does have `blez` and `bltz` in hardware, as well as `bne` and `beq` between two registers.

---

And BTW, the comments on your `IsDigit` don't match the code: they say that `$a0` *is* a character, but actually you're using `$a0` as a pointer to load a character.  So **you're passing a `char` by reference for no apparent reason**, or passing a string and taking the first character.

```
# IsDigit - tests a if a character a digit or not 
# arguments:
#   $a0 = character byte (must be zero-extended, or sign-extended which is the same thing for low ASCII bytes like '0'..'9')
# return value:
#   $v0 = boolean: 1 -> it is an ASCII decimal digit in [0-9]

IsDigit:
    addiu   $v0, $a0, -'0'            # wraps to a large unsigned value if below '0'
    sltiu   $v0, $v0, 10              # $v0 = bool($v0 < 10U)  (unsigned compare)
    jr      $ra
```

MARS's assembler refuses to assemble `-'0'` as an immediate, you have to write it as `-48` or `-0x30`.  clang's assembler has no problem with `addiu   $v0, $a0, -'0'`.

If you write `subiu  $v0, $a0, '0'`, MARS constructs `'0'` using a braindead lui+ori, because it's very simplistic for extended pseudo-instructions that most assemblers don't support.  (MIPS doesn't have a `subi` instruction, only `addi`/`addiu`, both of which take sign-extended immediates.)

Comment: Also related: [How to do less than or equal in Assembly Language(MIPS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22736836) for more branchless compares