# Count the Number of Consistent Strings in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

So this is a problem off leetcode and I'm having some issues with it.. I've seen code that solves this problem posted to the discussion's portion of leetcode, but I was wondering if anyone could help me solve it with some of the code I've already written.. Here's what the problem is asking:

> You are given a string `allowed` consisting of distinct characters and
> an array of strings `words`. A string is consistent if all characters in
> the string appear in the string `allowed`.   Return the number of
> consistent strings in the array words.
>
> Example:
> Input: `allowed = "ab"`,  `words => ["ad","bd","aaab","baa","badab"]`
>
> Output: 2
>
> Explanation: Strings "aaab" and "baa" are consistent since they only
> contain characters 'a' and 'b'.

Here's my code so far:

Note: allowed contains a single string

```
#include <string.h>

int countConsistentStrings(char * allowed, char ** words, int wordsSize){
    
    int real_count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < wordsSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < strlen(allowed); j++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < strlen(words[i]); k++)
            {
                if(words[i][k] != allowed[j])
                {
                    // stuff goes here?
                }
            }

        }
    }


    return real_count;
}
```

I'm able to iterate through the strings in the array char by char and compare them to allowed's chars... But I really don't know where to go from there. I've tried keeping tallies of stuff and using comparisons but then I run into issues of whether words[i] is less than strlen(allowed) or vice-versa..

I know there's probably easier ways to do this problem (as I've seen posted on the discussion portion of leetcode) but I'm wondering if there's anyway to solve it using what I've already done?

Thank you anyone who can help me out with this... I feel like I'm "almost" there with this problem, but I've also been stuck on it quite a while so I'm ready for any explanations I can get.

Comment: Does `allowed` have a _single_ word? Or, can it have _multiple_ words separated by whitespace? Can you use `strcmp` et al.? _Side note:_ `for(int j = 0; j < strlen(allowed); j++)` (e.g.) is very slow (O(n^2) instead of O(n)). Better to do: `for(int j = 0, len = strlen(allowed); j < len; j++)`

Comment: allowed consists of one string. I'll edit the question so that's clear.. And would my loop be n^2 because it has to iterate through strlen(allowed) each time to get the value?

Comment: If `allowed` only has _one_ word in it [and I assume it has _no_ other whitespace], you can only return a single [boolean] value: (e.g.) `1=match, 0=nomatch` ??? That assumes that a given string is _only_ in `words` one time (i.e. `words` entries are unique). If `words` _can_ repeat a string, then the return becomes a _count_ of the number of matching `words` entries. If they are unique, you can `break` out of the loop if you find the first match (i.e. it's faster--always a good things for sites like leetcode). Otherwise, you have to loop through _all_ `words` entries? Which do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strchr` function to help detect if a character exists in `allowed`.  The function works like this:

> ```
>    char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
>    The strchr() function returns a pointer to the first occurrence
>    of the character c in the string s.
>    The strchr() and strrchr() functions return a pointer to the
>    matched character or NULL if the character is not found.
> ```

So testing for NULL allows you to check if the character in question is found in `allowed`.  With this function, you can remove one of your loops and just iterate through each character in a given word looking for matches.  With this in mind, I think it's easier to assume all words *do* match then subtract out the ones that don't match.

Here is some code that illustrates what I mean.  I created a main function that calls `countConsistentStrings` with some test data I used to verify the behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int countConsistentStrings(char *allowed, char **words, int wordsSize)
{
    int real_count = wordsSize;
    for(int i = 0; i < wordsSize; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < strlen(words[i]); k++)
        {
            // if character is not found, then it's not a consistent string
            // so we can just lower the count and exit the loop right now
            if(strchr(allowed, words[i][k]) == NULL)
            {
                real_count--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return real_count;
}

int main()
{
    char *allowed = "abcde";
    char *words[] =
    {
       "abcde",
       "fghji",
       "d",
       "l",
       "abcdef"
    };
    int wordcount = sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]);
    int count;

    printf("Finding consistent strings among %d words\n", wordcount);
    
    count = countConsistentStrings(allowed, words, wordcount);
    
    printf("Consistent string count: %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strchr` is inefficient for this, and solutions to “leetcode” problems and other contest problems should aim for efficiency, particularly when it is easily available. Some of these problems are timed and have test cases designed to cause inefficient solutions to fail the time requirement.

Comment: While there are more efficient ways to solve the problem, the OP wrote "I know there's probably easier ways to do this problem (as I've seen posted on the discussion portion of leetcode) but I'm wondering if there's anyway to solve it using what I've already done?"  So he was more interested in understanding the logic of possible solutions than squeezing every cycle out of the runtime performance.  That's the motivation behind what I provided.

Comment: The fact that people think they want faster horses does not mean you should not give them a car.

Comment: You left in the `strlen` call in the `for` loop conditional expression, so at a minimum, that could be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an O(N) solution.  So you don't have to rescan `allowed` for each character, you can just use a lookup table.  Easy since chars are typically 8-bit and an array of 256 true/value values is easy.

```
int countConsistentStrings(char * allowed, char ** words, int wordsSize) {

    // put all the allowed chars into a table of booleans

    unsigned int table[256] = {0}; // 256 assumes 8-bit char
    int real_count = 0;
    const char* ptr = allowed;

    while (*ptr)
    {
        char c = *ptr;
        table[(unsigned char)c)] = 1;   // table[c] = 1 to indicate "is allowed"
        ptr++;
    }

    // evaluate each word and see if each char in word
    // is in the allowed list of chars
    
    for(int i = 0; i < wordsSize; i++)
    {
        char* word = words[i];
        int consistent = 1;
        while (*word && consistent)
        {
            char c = *word;
            consistent = table[(unsigned char)c]; // lookup to see if this char is allowed
            word++;
        }
        real_count += consistent;
    }

    return real_count;
}
```

Comment: I was considering the table approach myself. I think `table` can be faster if it's a `char`

Comment: Okay, let me see if I can follow this... You created an array named table and set the indexes that equal the individual asci values of allowed's chars equal to 1. You then use this table to compare the chars of words[i]?

Comment: Why write `[256] = {0}; // 256 assumes 8-bit char`, deliberately building in a prerequisite unnecessarily? Use `[UCHAR_MAX+1u] = {0};`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - for the purposes of teaching someone new to coding, just going with hardcoded defaults that work near universally is probably for the best.

Comment: @CraigEstey: If the allowed characters are always lower-case letters (or otherwise span at most 32 or 64 code points), we can even build a bitmap in a `uint32_t` (or `uint_fast32_t`).  Depending on the machine, `c - ='a'` / `if (c >= 26) break;` / `if(allowed & (1<<c))` or something like that could be as good as byte loads, and avoids building the array.  (Especially good if you can drop the range check).  e.g. on x86 `sub eax, 'a'` / (`cmp eax, 25` / `jae nope`) / `bt edx, eax` / `jnc nope`.  ARM can also build a shift into other instructions.  But yeah, for large inputs memory's prob. best.

Comment: @CraigEstey: Some microarchitectures have an extra cycle of latency or something on byte loads vs. register-width (word) loads.  Probably not a big deal here, and for all but the largest problems that difference would be lost in the noise, and/or zeroing (and touching) only 256 bytes instead of 1024 bytes makes up the difference in startup overhead.  So yeah, I'd go with a `_Bool` array (or `char`, but using C99 `_Bool` lets the implementation pick whatever size it thinks a boolean array should be; usually 1 byte.  Or `#include <stdbool.h>` so you can call it `bool`.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming standard C library functions are allowed, the following uses [`size_t strspn(const char *dest, const char *src)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strspn), which "*returns the length of the maximum initial segment (span) of the null-terminated byte string pointed to by `dest`, that consists of only the characters found in the null-terminated byte string pointed to by `src`.*".

```
#include <string.h>

int countConsistentStrings(char *allowed, char **words, int wordsSize)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < wordsSize; i++)
    {
        char *word = words[i];
        if(word[strspn(word, allowed)] == '\0')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: `strspn` is inefficient for this (it could be implemented so that it is efficient per call, but the problem specification calls for applying the same set of allowed characters to multiple strings), and solutions to “leetcode” problems and other contest problems should aim for efficiency, particularly when it is easily available. Some of these problems are timed and have test cases designed to cause inefficient solutions to fail the time requirement.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `strspn` could be marginally more efficient in this case if it returned a pointer to the first non-matching character, instead of the count of matching characters. That would save one pointer indexing per word being checked, though in practice that's likely to be offset by the library optimizations for `strspn` as opposed to handcrafted loops. That said, I never claimed that the above will provide the ultimate performance, so feel free to post your version of what you consider "*best*".

Comment: I am not competing. I am working to improve the quality of answers. Inefficient answers should be discouraged. [Selbie’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66251696/298225) has the correct answer, so there is no need for me or anybody else to enter a new one, although I would like to see it improved a bit.

Comment: `strspn` has to [internally] build/rebuild a 256 element table from the `accept` string on _each_ call [for `glibc`, at least], so it's [probably] spending more time doing that than actual lookup/match

Comment: @EricPostpischil The "*correct*" answer depends on untold assumptions about the number and size of strings, expected distribution of characters, and internal implementation of `strspn`.