# Recursive Procedure Whose Calls Resemble a Binary Tree in MIPS

Tags: recursion, assembly, tree, mips

I'm working on an assignment and am having difficulty understanding how to properly code the following problem in C.

```
int choose(int n, int k){
    if (k == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n == k) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n < k) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return choose(n-1, k-1) + choose(n-1, k);
    }
}
```

My thoughts were to use three registers for storing the values onto the stack with each call `$s0, $s1, $s2`, where `$s0` will contain the value of updated `n`; `$s1` would maintain the value of `k`; and `$s2` would hold the value of `k` in the second `choose(n-1, k)` since that value will only decrease when the parent call changes it.  The reason I chose this is because the value of `k` isn't subtracted from each call in this one, it should be the same until the parent decrements it in a previous call.

Here is the `Choose` procedure that I'm trying to do.  Problem is that I'm not getting the correct answer, of course.

```
Choose:
    #store current values onto stack
    addi $sp, $sp, -16
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    sw $s0, 4($sp)
    sw $s1, 8($sp)
    sw $s2, 12($sp)

    #check values meet criteria to add to $v0       
    beq $s1, $0, one
    beq $s0, $s1, one
    blt $s0, $s1, zero
    beq $s2, $0, one

    #no branches passed so decrement values of n and k
    subi $s0, $s0, 1
    subi $s1, $s1, 1

    #move values of registers to $a's for argument passing
    move $a0, $s0
    move $a1, $s1

    jal Choose  #call procedure again

    #this is where I'm having my problems
    #not sure how to loop the procedure to get
    #the second half of the equation Choose(n-1,k)
    #which is the reason for the next 2 lines of code
    move $a2, $s2
    jal Choose

    add $v0, $v0, $v1
    j Choose_Exit


#add one to $v1 from branch passed
one:
    addi $v1, $v1, 1
    j Choose_Exit

#branch returns 0   
zero:
    addi $v1, $v1, 0
    j Choose_Exit

#return values to caller from stack
Choose_Exit:
    lw $s2, 12($sp)
    lw $s1, 8($sp)
    lw $s0, 4($sp)
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 16
    jr $ra
```

So I'm having a problem understanding how to properly implement this recursive procedure twice to add them together.  I can understand how to create a recursive procedure in MIPS to perform a factorial, since that is always the definition of recursion for any language.  But using recursion with differing arguments and then add them all together is confusing me to no end.

When written out on paper, I understand that this procedure can be represented by a binary tree of parents and children.  The parent being the single function `Choose(n,k)` and the children being `Choose(n-1, k-1) + Choose(n-1, k)` and once one of the leaf children branches from the `if` statement, it passes a digit to the parent who will wait for the other callee portion of the addition to return its value, etc etc etc.

Any help to point me in the correct direction as to what I'm doing wrong with my approach would be great.  I understand the beginning, I understand the end, just need some assistance to help understand the most important part of the middle.

Comment: Step 1: Establish a convention - Arguments go into `$a0` and `$a1`, the return value into `$v0` and registers `$s0`-`$s7` are callee-save (i.e. must be restored as given before exit). Step 2: Adhere to the convention - You know where the arguments are now. If you need to use an `$s` register, save it on the stack at the beginning and restore it at the ending. If you need to preserve a value across a call, move it into an `$s` register. Step 3: Program - Once you have got the result of *choose(n-1, k-1)* in `$v0` *move it* to a preserved register and call *choose(n, k-1)*. Continue from here.

Comment: Note that "*moving into an `$s` register*" qualifies as using it. So, as said, you also need to ...

Comment: @MargaretBloom thanks for your input.  I do understand your description of conventions and why it is important.  My professor has taught us exactly what you said and you are correct in that I should be using that convention. With that said I'm still not sure how I can achieve what I'm trying to with my current code.  I'd really appreciate more input in how I can have to instances of a single recursive procedure occur when different values of the argument are needed.  I didn't include all the code where `$a#` registers are used to pass the arguments when this procedure is first called.

Comment: I can't understand what is blocking you. Calling a recursive procedure is the same as calling a non-recursive one. You have two calls - save your `$a` registers in the stack as you will overwrite them in calling the first procedure and you still need them for the second call. Update their values and do the first call. Save the value of `$v0` and restore the `$a` registers from the stack then update their value again (this time for the second invocation). Do the call and then add to `$v0` the old `$v0` you saved somewhere. This is ordinary assembly programming, you may want to brush up on it.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I appreciate your constructive criticism.  My problem is not understanding how to invoke a call recursively, building my stack, or passing along the values.  I do understand that.  My issue with this assignment is how to invoke two separate cases of a single recursive procedure.  As a student who has just started Assembly, I tried to brush up on it but my experiences in this language is limited.  Hence my searches online for help which eventually led to this thread.  I do appreciate your help and blunt input though.

Comment: It was not a critic, rather an advice. Start with the basics and move forward after you feel confident. :) Good luck with the study!

Comment: @MargaretBloom Honestly, I appreciate your input!  The first thing I did after reading your posts were to check my actual code and ensure that I was following the rules for passing arguments from `$a#` registers, returning values within `$v#` registers, and checked my stack setup.  All my posts in this forum, I've always taken all feedback about my questions seriously.  I come here for help from all that know much much more than me.  My replies to you were not taken as hurtful, but helpful.  Seriously thank you!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close.

You established your stack frame with four words for: return address, arg1, arg2, and save for return value.

Your main snag was that after the first call to your function, you have to save the `$v0` onto the stack [as Margaret mentioned above].

Here's some code that I believe will work. It is very similar to yours, but I wrote it from scratch. It has the correct "push"/"pop" of the first call's return value.

I did add one small optimization for the early escape [non-recursive] cases: they omit creating the stack frame.

Anyway, here it is:

```
#@+
#   int
#   choose(int n, int k)
#   {
#
#       if (k == 0)
#           return 1;
#
#       if (n == k)
#           return 1;
#
#       if (n < k)
#           return 0;
#
#       return choose(n - 1,k - 1) + choose(n - 1,k);
#   }
#@-

    .text

# choose -- choose
#
# RETURNS:
#   v0 -- return value
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- n
#   a1 -- k
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- temp for 1st return value
choose:
    beqz    $a1,choose_one          # k == 0? if yes, fly
    beq     $a0,$a1,choose_one      # n == k? if yes, fly
    blt     $a0,$a1,choose_zero     # n < k? if yes, fly

    # establish stack frame (preserve ra/a0/a1 + space for v0)
    sub     $sp,$sp,16
    sw      $ra,12($sp)
    sw      $a0,8($sp)
    sw      $a1,4($sp)

    addi    $a0,$a0,-1              # get n - 1 (common to both calls)

    # choose(n - 1,k - 1)
    addi    $a1,$a1,-1              # get k - 1
    jal     choose
    sw      $v0,0($sp)              # save 1st return value (on _stack_)

    # choose(n - 1,k)
    addi    $a1,$a1,1               # get k (from k - 1)
    jal     choose

    lw      $t0,0($sp)              # "pop" first return value from stack
    add     $v0,$t0,$v0             # sum 1st and 2nd values

    # restore from stack frame
    lw      $ra,12($sp)
    lw      $a0,8($sp)
    lw      $a1,4($sp)
    add     $sp,$sp,16
    jr      $ra                     # return

choose_one:
    li      $v0,1
    jr      $ra

choose_zero:
    li      $v0,0
    jr      $ra
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> First off, I like how you noted the procedure as you did before you called it. I'm going to steal that!

Be my guest! It's from many years of writing asm. For a primer on my thoughts about how to write asm well, see my answer: [MIPS linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538325/mips-linked-list/36560575#36560575)

> I've tried this and it works. I need to experiment with your code to understand why the stack is manipulated when it is (always thought it had to be at the very beginning and end of a proc).

Normally, the stack frame *is* established at the proc start and restored from at the proc end. Your code for handling the "quick escape" [non-recursive] cases *was* correct, based on having already established the frame.

This was just a small optimization. But, it comes from the fact that because mips has so many registers that, for small functions, we don't even need a stack frame, particularly if the function is a "leaf" or "tail" (i.e. it doesn't call any other function).

For smaller [non-recursive] functions, sometimes we can get away with a one word stack frame that just preserves `$ra` (e.g.): `fncA` calls `fncB`, but `fncB` is a leaf. `fncA` needs a frame but `fncB` does *not*. In fact, if we control both functions and we *know* that `fncB` does *not* modify a given temp register (e.g. `$t9`), we can save the return address there instead of creating a stack frame in `fncA`:

```
fncA:
    move    $t9,$ra                 # preserve return address
    jal     fncB                    # call fncB
    jr      $t9                     # return

fncB:
    # do stuff ...
    jr      $ra                     # return
```

Ordinarily, we couldn't rely upon `fncB` preserving `$t9` because, according to the mips ABI, `fncB` is at liberty to modify/trash *any* register that is *not* `$sp` or `$s0-$s7`. But, if we craft the functions such that we consider `fncB` to be "private" to `fncA` (e.g. like a C `static` function that only `fncA` has access to), we can do *whatever* we want.

Believe it or not, `fncA` above *is* ABI conforming.

A given *callee* (e.g. `fncA`) does *not* need to preserve `$ra` for [the sake of] its *caller*, just for itself. And, what is important is the *value* inside `$ra`, not the specific register. A callee only needs to preserve `$s0-$s7`, ensure that `$sp` has the same value at exit as entry, and that it returns to the correct address in caller [which the `jr $t9` does--because it has the *value* that was in `$ra` when `fncA` was called].

> I like your use of the temp register.

An extra register is *required* because, in mips, we can *not* do arithmetic operations from memory operands. mips can only do `lw/sw`. (i.e.) There is *no* such thing as:

```
    add     $v0,$v0,0($sp)
```

I used `$t0` for simplicity/clarity because, when you need a temp reg, `$t0-$t9` are the usual ones to use. The code "reads better" when using `$t0`.But, this is *just* a convention.

In the mips ABI, `$a0-$a3` can be modified, as can `$v1` as only `$s0-$s7` need to be preserved. And, "modification" means that they can be used to hold any value or used for any purpose.

In the above link, note that `strlen` increments `$a0` directly to find the end of the string. It is using `$a0` for a useful purpose, but, as far as the caller to it is concerned, `$a0` is being "trashed" [by `strlen`]. This usage *is* ABI conforming.

In `choose`, I could have used just about *any* register: `$v1`, `$a2-$a3` instead of `$t0`. In fact, at that particular point in `choose`, `$a0` is no longer needed, so it could have been used in place of `$t0`. Although for `choose`, we are *non*-ABI conforming (because we save/restore `$a0-$a1`), this would work in `choose`, because we restore the original value of `$a0` from the function epilog [stack frame pop], preserving the recursive nature of the function.

As I said, `$t0-$t9` are the usual registers to use for scratch space. But, I've written functions that use all 10 of them, and still needed more (e.g. drawing into a frame buffer using the Bresenham circle algorithm). `$v0-$v1` and `$a0-$a3` can be used as temp regs to get an additional 6. If necessary, `$s0-$s7` can be preserved in the stack frame, solely to free them up to use as more temp regs.

Comment: Craig Estey.  First off, I like how you noted the procedure as you did before you called it.  I'm going to steal that!  I've tried this and it works.  I need to experiment with your code to understand why the stack is manipulated when it is (always thought it had to be at the very beginning and end of a proc).  I like your use of the temp register.  I'm going to run it step by step and watch the register and values to see how yours is performed exactly.  I want to try to write one my own and update my post with my own.

Comment: Craig Estey, excellently worded and detailed updated response.  I like the fact that you placed the additions to the stack frame after the equality statements since further additions to the stack wouldn't be necessary.  Your input is also great because you also tell me where I do have the correct approach, yet specify where it can be altered to be optimized.  Not trying to sound too much of a suck-up, but these types of responses is why I love these boards.  Learned a lot.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I rewrite the assembly code **WITHOUT** checking it.

1. There are delay-slots to consider so better to make smart use of them and to make them explicit to avoid aggregations of implicit nop instructions after branch instructions.
2. Reverse the order of calls between choose(n - 1,k - 1) and choose(n - 1,k) for smarter usage of $a0 and $a1 and of the stack.
3. Restrain stack usage for only calling choose(n - 1,k) and use tail calling for calling choose(n - 1,k - 1).
4. It makes more sense to stack the value of a0-1 and not a0.
5. We accumulate everything into $v0 instead of stacking it. We keep $t0 as a local result to add to $v0 because it is cheap while we can discard it by doing direct things with $v0.
6. As a result, the overall changes should make icache happier with less instructions and dcache happier with less stack space.

The assembly code:

```
#@+
#   int
#   choose(int n, int k)
#   {
#
#       if (k == 0)
#           return 1;
#
#       if (n == k)
#           return 1;
#
#       if (n < k)
#           return 0;
#
#       return choose(n - 1,k - 1) + choose(n - 1,k);
#   }
#@-

    .text

# choose -- choose
#
# RETURNS:
#   v0 -- return value
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- n
#   a1 -- k
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- temp for local result to accumulate into v0
choose:
    j       choose_rec
    addui   $v0, $zr, 0             # initialize $v0 to 0 before calling
choose_rec:
    beqz    $a1,choose_one          # k == 0? if yes, fly
    addui   $t0,$zr,1               # branch delay-slot with $t0 = 1
    beq     $a0,$a1,choose_one      # n == k? if yes, fly
    nop                             # branch delay-slot with $t0 = 1 already done
    blt     $a0,$a1,choose_zero     # n < k? if yes, fly
    addui   $t0,$zr,0               # branch delay-slot with $t0 = 0

    # establish stack frame (preserve ra/a0/a1)
    sub     $sp,$sp,12
    addui   $a0,$a0,-1              # get n - 1 (common to both calls)
    sw      $ra,8($sp)
    sw      $a0,4($sp)          
    jal     choose_rec              # choose(n - 1,k)
    sw      $a1,0($sp)

    # restore from stack frame
    lw      $ra,8($sp)
    lw      $a0,4($sp)
    lw      $a1,0($sp)
    add     $sp,$sp,12

    # choose(n - 1,k - 1)
    j       choose_rec              # tail call: jump instead of call
    addi    $a1,$a1,-1              # get k - 1

choose_one:
choose_zero:
    jr      $ra                     # return   
    addui   $v0,$v0,$t0             # branch delay-slot with $v0 += $t0
```